# Quebra de linha dentro de uma query MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, fpdf

Olá alguem pode me ajudar com quebra de linha dentro de uma query mysql?

O código esta assim:

```
CONCAT('Origem -> ',vEnderecoOrigem,' \r\nDestino ->',vEnderecoDestino)
```

O resultado:

```
Origem -> Rua Exemplo Origem Destino -> Rua Exemplo Destino
```

Resultado esperado:

```
Origem -> Rua Exemplo Origem 
Destino -> Rua Exemplo Destino
```

A tentei o `CHAR(10),(13),\n` e não consigo o resultado esperado. É possível fazer isso?

OBS: É um gerador de *.pdf* e *.xls*, o nome é *FPDF*.

Comment: No PHP utilize a função `nl2br`

Comment: Como está fazendo para verificar o resultado? Se já tentou tudo isso, provavelmete o problema está na sua aplicação ou teste, e não na query. Praticamente toda ferramenta decente de MySQL (como o "finado" MySQL Query Browser, por exemplo) permite ver os campos em binário para ter certeza.

Comment: Tentei com o nl2br e ele imprimiu o <br /> junto.
Seguinte estou modificando os valores de saída de um relatório. A aplicação esta imprimindo tudo ok, o problema é que os endereços são grandes então preciso da quebra de linha para facilitar a visualização. Já usei outras ferramentas para gerar PDFS só que essa em particular quando tento inserir HTML ela não responde... Não faço ideia do que possa ser.

Comment: Acredito que não seja uma operação MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente o problema não era na query e sim na aplicação. Encontrei a solução no site do FPDF utilizando uma [MultiCell](http://www.fpdf.org/), essa função já cria uma célula e quebra as linhas dependendo do tamanho da string. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o ***[CONCAT_WS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)***, deve resolver o problema:

```
CONCAT_WS('\n', 'Origem -> '.vEnderecoOrigem, 'Destino ->'.vEnderecoDestino)
```

Comment: O problema do autor não é esse. O CONCAT_WS dá na mesma. Vide comentários, ele está gravando a quebra, o problema é na aplicação dele. O BR está no DB, mas o código que gera o PDF nao está correto (na verdade a pergunta é fora de escopo - problema não reproduzido, pois não procede a afirmação - o autor teria que atualizar a pergunta com a situação real)

Comment: Entendi, consegui resolver o problema obrigado.